# PL/SQL annoymous procedure + cursor problems

Tags: plsql, cursor, procedure

I am trying to write an anonymous block as follows, but it always give me error messages as

> Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following. ( ) , * @ % & - + / at mod remainder rem  and or || multiset.

I don't know what it means.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try to strip down your code next time to a minimal but complete example - see [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `:` in front of the `=`in several places, e.g. here:

```
get_sectno='1031';
```

The assignment operator in PL/SQL is `:=`- `=` is (just like in plain SQL) comparison for equality.

You're also missing the `;` at the end of every call to

```
lowest_average (get_term, get_sectno, get_ctitle, get_sid, get_sname, get_average)
```